# Parabolic subgroups of an arbitary linear algebraic group in terms of flag stabilizers?

Tags: algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group embedded as a closed subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$.

By definition, a [*parabolic subgroup*](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Parabolic_subgroup) of $G$ is a closed subgroup $P \subseteq G$ such that $G/P$ is a projective algebraic variety.

For $G = GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ or $G = SL(n,\mathbb{C})$ [it is known](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/249BW16Page/handouts/stdpar.pdf) that the parabolic subgroups are exactly the stabilizers in $G$ of flags of linear subspaces 
$$
\{0\} \subsetneq V_1 \subsetneq V_2 \subsetneq \ldots \subsetneq V_k \subsetneq \mathbb{C}^n,
\quad
0 \leq k \leq n-1.
$$
A different flag will yield a different parabolic subgroup. Is there a similar general description of parabolic subgroups for an arbitrary embedded linear algebraic groups $G$ in terms of flags?